# How to move turtles back to the patches that it come from

Tags: netlogo

I have built the road shapefile which already intersected with patches. I want the turtle to move on the road that I had assigned.

```
to go
  ask turtles
  [
    step 
    avoid-wall
  ]
  tick
end

to-report coinflip?
  report random 2 = 0
end

to avoid-wall
  if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 3 = black [set heading heading - 180]
end

to step
  ifelse coinflip? [rt random 60] [lt random 60]
  fd random 3
end
```

Actually, I intend to let the turtle move out of the assigned patches. But I still want them to come back in the next tick or just the few tick later. Some turtles come back and some do not (according to my code). How should I fix the code?

I have tried to use this code in [Turtles moving in a pattern (Netlogo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171765/turtles-moving-in-a-pattern-netlogo) but it does not work (I think that it does not work because my patches are a narrow road, not an area.)

Comment: This is just a guess at what might be wrong, but perhaps `[pcolor] of patch-ahead 3` isn't sufficient to detect walls ahead in every circumstance. For example, if the wall is closer than 3 patches away, `patch-ahead 3` won't detect it, because `patch-ahead` always looks _exactly_ that distance ahead.